Sci-fi book where the survivor of a bombing is turned into a cyborg
I only remember parts of the book vaguely as I had it as a child. But I think it starts out in a city and there's a bombing or some other disaster and when the government come in to look for survivors, a woman finds a dead boy but says he's still alive.
They take him back to some secret base and they perform surgery on him to try and save him but they had to turn him into a cyborg, I believe.
Later in the book I feel like I remember a part where he had to download some information into his brain or something like that in order to carry out a secret mission.

Do you have any idea when this was published? When (year) did you read it? Can you describe the cover?

You might also review this checklist

I read it between around 2010-2016 if i remember correctly, but I don't know when it was published sorry. It wasn't an old book so I think it was published in the 2000s

Sorry I can't remember much and be more helpful
